# Forming a Relationship between DB Tables (C#)

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have two tables in my database: category_table and subcategory_table.

Category table has the following columns: `id (int, PK), Category (varchar)`
Subcategory table has the following columns: `id (int, PK), Category (int), Subcategory (varchar)`

I'm trying to make a form where a user can add/delete both categories and subcategories. There are two comboboxs (where the user can see the current categories. Subcategories can only be seen if their respective category is selected from the first combobox).

The issue I'm having is relating the `category_table` (id) Primary Key, to the `subcategory_table` (Category); so that whatever Category is selected in the first combobox, when a Subcategory is added, the (id) of that Category from `category_table` gets assigned to the (Category) column in `subcategory_table`.

I understand that Foreign Key can be used; however, I don't know HOW in this situation.

Adding a Category:

```
    //ADD CATEGORY
    private void addcat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO category_table (Category) VALUES(@cat);", sqlconnection))
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", this.cat_txtbx.Text);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Adding a Subcategory:

```
    //ADD SUBCATEGORY
    private void addsubcat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(combobox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a category in which to add a subcategory.", "Invalid Operation: Data Missing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO subcategory_table (Subcategory) VALUES(@subcat);", sqlconnection))
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subcat", this.subcat_txtbx.Text);
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean "how" in regards to how you would design the relationship between the tables? Or how you would create that relationship on SQL Server? Or how to pull the relationship into your front end?

Comment: @xboxremote The specific thing that Im having trouble with assigning the id of a Category from the `category_table' to the Category column of the `subcategory_table'. I've tried to do a Foreign Key, but the problem is that the id from the `category_table` never gets assigned to the Category column of the `subcategory_table`.

Comment: Well in that case we'd have to see how you're inserting the data. Can you post that code?

Comment: I've posted the code for how I add both category and subcategories.

Comment: @xboxremote Also, here is how I assigned the Foreign Key (I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio): `Primary Key Table: category_table, categoryid` `Foreign Key Table: subcategory_table, categoryid`. Whenever I add a new subcategory, it gets a `null` value instead of the categoryid from `category_table`.

Comment: So am I correct in assuming your categories are already populated by this point? It sounds like you need to query the PK for the categories and tie that into the combo box. Does that make sense? I'd write it out but I'm my phone, not my computer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to accomplish, why not structure your database tables like so:

```
Category:
·categoryId int AUTO_INCREMENT (PRIMARY KEY)
·name varchar(255)

CategoryRelationship:
·id int AUTO_INCREMENT (PRIMARY KEY)
·categoryId int
·parentCategoryId int
```

This way, all categories (parent categories, solo categories, child or subcategories) will reside in the `Category` table, and any/all relationships between them are identified in the `CategoryRelationship` table.

For example, let's say I have six categories: Animal, Vegetable, Mineral, Cat, Tomato, and Sandstone. They would all be stored in the `Category` table, like so:

```
1  'Animal'
2  'Vegetable'
3  'Mineral'
4  'Cat'
5  'Tomato'
6  'Sandstone'
```

Now I want to keep track of the fact that Tomato is a subcategory of Vegetable, and Cat is a subcategory of Animal, etc, all in the `CategoryRelationship` table:

```
1  4  1    // Cat (4) is a subcategory of Animal (1)
2  5  2    // Tomato (5) is a subcategory of Vegetable (2)
3  6  3    // Sandstone (6) is a subcategory of Mineral (3)
```

As an added bonus, a given category can belong to multiple parent categories, thus eliminating duplication:

```
1  4  1    // Cat (4) is a subcategory of Animal (1)
2  5  2
3  6  3
4  4  7    // Cat (4) is also a subcategory of Feline (7)
```

Or, a given category can have multiple subcategories:

```
1  4  1    // Cat (4) is a subcategory of Animal (1)
2  5  2
3  6  3
4  4  7    
5  8  1    // Dog (8) is a subcategory of Animal (1)
6  9  1    // Horse (9) is a subcategory of Animal (1)
```

Does that help?

Comment: But each category has several subcategories, and subcategories are loaded into a combobox based on what is selected in the first combobox (the Category combobox).

Comment: Hmm. I think I'm not understanding your question. :)

Comment: I added an example for a given category having several subcategories. To view all subcategories for a given category, the query would look something like this: select categoryId
from CategoryRelationship
where parentCategoryId = a_ParentCategoryId
order by categoryId

Answer (score 0):

Taking exactly the code you have in your add subcategory method, what you need in order to create that foreign key relationship is added:

```
//ADD SUBCATEGORY
private void addsubcat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(combobox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a category in which to add a subcategory.", "Invalid Operation: Data Missing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO subcategory_table (Category, Subcategory) VALUES(@category, @subcat);", sqlconnection))
        {
            // Added this next line, and the corresponding parts in the INSERT statement above.
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", this.combobox1.SelectedValue); 
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subcat", this.subcat_txtbx.Text);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

-- edit for more information --

I would recommend renaming the combobox1 to something meaningful, like "categories" or something that makes sense for your purpose.

Also, I notice that there is not an enforced foreign key relationship, because you said that null values are being added. The way you have presented what you are trying to accomplish, I am taking away from it that there is Category and Subcategory, but no more levels. If there are more levels, then @mycargus has provided a good alternative to data structure. If there is just those two levels, it looks like a Subcategory requires having a main "Category."

I would recommend having that foreign key relationship enforced on the database side to prevent null values, and ids that do not exist in the "category_table"

Comment: I get the following SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@category". And this won't work, because it's not assigning the id from `category_table` to the Category column in `subcategory_table`.

Comment: That SqlException might be from a typo in the added parameter. Check to make sure they match. The edit I made to the insert statement is to allow for the id from category_table to be assigned to the Category column in subcategory_table, which is, as I understand your question, what you are trying to accomplish. Does that help?

Comment: I think he's saying the ID in the combo box isn't necessarily the PK from that table. So your method would assign an arbitrary FK.

Comment: The ID from the `category_table` should be set to the `ValueMember` property of the `ComboBox` in order to support what the OP is trying to accomplish. John's code already shows that he is checking to make sure there is a `SelectedItem` by making sure the `Text` property isn't empty in the `ComboBox`, so as long as the ID is properly assigned behind the name from the `category_table`, getting `SelectedValue` will get the underlying ID for the INSERT statement.

Comment: @John How is the ComboBox populated? Do you have the ValueMember and DisplayMember properties both set, or just the DisplayMember?

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure, which

step 1. Selects the "category id" based on the selected category from the drop down

step 2. and then write the insert into the subcategory table with the category id obtained in step 1.

And call the stored procedure from your addsubcat_Click method.